# Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '(() => dynamic)?

Tags: flutter

I got this error when I try to delay a method for saving the token device.

```
    final pushnoti = new PushNoti();
    pushnoti.configurePushNoti(context);
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), pushnoti.saveTokenDevice(currentUid));
    return StreamBuilder<UserData>()
```

This is the method definition:

```
  saveTokenDevice(String currentUid) async {
    tokenDevice = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    if (tokenDevice != null) {
      var tokenRef =  _database
        .collection(user_database)
        .document(currentUid);

      if (tokenRef != null){
      await tokenRef.updateData({
        'TokenDevice': FieldValue.arrayUnion([tokenDevice])
      }
      );
      }
      else {
      }
    }
```

What I would like to do is delay that method after the user has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thew `delayed` constructor requires a function that returns a value or a `Future`, but the way you wrote the code it is the result of your `saveTokenDevice` function, which is a `Future`. It should probably be this:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => pushnoti.saveTokenDevice(currentUid));
```

Source: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html

Answer (score 0):

You should change here like this:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () { pushnoti.saveTokenDevice(currentUid); });
```

**Edit:**

Ok, @wujek is speeder than me with 31 sec.

Comment: I don't think this actually works, you are missing a return statement if you are using the bloc syntax. To omit return you need the 'fat-arrow' syntax.